# NSTableView animation bug while using NSTableViewDiffableDataSource

Tags: swift, macos, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nstableview, appkit

I am using NSTableViewDiffableDataSource. When I do a multiple delete, I see the wrong insert-animation after (flicker and moving from top or bottom). How fix it?

[image]

```
// I am using UUID instead of NSManagedObjectID because when I create a new NSManagedObject it first has a temporary objectID.
func configureDataSource() {
        let dataSource : NSTableViewDiffableDataSource<String, UUID> = .init(tableView: tableView) { table, column, index, objectID in
            let request = NSFetchRequest<Task>()
            request.entity = Task.entity()
            request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = %@", argumentArray: [objectID])
            
            guard let task = try? self.viewContext.fetch(request).first as? Task else {
                return NSView()
            }
            let cell = self.create(viewFor: column, task: task)
            return cell
        }
        dataSource.defaultRowAnimation = .effectGap
        dataSource.sectionHeaderViewProvider = nil
        
        self.dataSource = dataSource
        
    }

func storeDidReloadContent() {
        
    var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<String, UUID>()
        
    snapshot.appendSections([""])
    snapshot.appendItems(store.objects.compactMap{ $0.id }, toSection: "")
    dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: false)
        
}
    
func storeDidChangeContent(with snapshot: NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshotReference) {
        
    var newSnapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<String, UUID>()
    newSnapshot.appendSections([""])
    newSnapshot.appendItems(store.objects.compactMap{ $0.id }, toSection: "")
        
    dataSource.apply(newSnapshot, animatingDifferences: true)
}


// class ObjectFactory
// Batch operation
public func delete(objects: [T]) {
        
    let objectIDs = objects.compactMap{ $0.objectID }
        
    CoreDataStorage.shared.performBackground { privateContext in
        objectIDs.forEach{
            let object = privateContext.object(with: $0)
            privateContext.delete(object)
        }
        try? privateContext.save()
    }
        
}
```

PS: Store class (var store) incapsulate all works with NSFetchedResultController.
ObjectFactory class incapsulate all works with NSManagedObjects.
NSFetchedResultController works with only main NSManagedObjectContext.
Batch operation in NSTableView is pain :(

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How to fix this bug? This is not correct behavior.